# client server communication in Java

Tags: java, web-services, http

I am trying to set up a webserver on an old machine of mine. I have installed ubuntu server edition and aim to use it for the following:

I want to run a java program on the server. I want to be able to retrieve data from the program from another computer/phone using an internet connection. I also want to be able to give the program data, and get a response saying whether or not the data has been received correctly.

So for example:

- A .jar program runs on my server and holds a variable `x`
- I want to be able to query the value of `x` from another device (over the internet).
- I want to be able to set the value of `x` remotely from another device, and get a response saying it was successful in altering the value.

What are my options here? I would like to try and keep things simple. It is perhaps worth mentioning that I will be the only one using the system. The server will be used exclusively for dealing with the two requests outline above.

Is it simply the case of creating a java program that listens out for incoming requests and running that on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you mentioned, you can start with custom `ServerSocket` wrapper which will decode incoming requests and do as it's bid. Currently, whole frameworks are done to encapsulate common code of this task -- see my 3rd point.
2. Old-school java solution: use RMI. See [RMI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).
3. New-school java solution: devise some simple text-based protocol with 2 commands:

   - Read()
   - Set(newVal)
     Then implement that protocol over some new trendy Java framework, like Apache MINA, which is created specifically to facilitate quick development of network apps in Java.

I, personally, started with RMI for such kind of tasks. Since RMI is considered Core Java technology, it's wise to learn it.

Comment: Perhaps I should give RMI a look-over then. Will I need to install things like Apache on my web server? Thanks

Comment: @AlanAlbus you won't need Apache in any of these solutions. You may need Apache only if you want to communicate using HTTP protocol. For RMI and custom solution, you won't need anything except JRE. For Apache MINA, you'll need MINA library. They have decent tutorial too (though its' font is horrible).

Comment: You dont need Apache to use RMI, if you want to host a website on this server as well, you have to install a webserver-software - which could be Apache.

Comment: Thanks very much Victor. Thanks also quaylar